# How to check if installed OpenSSL version is >= 0.9.8k

Tags: php, openssl

I have a PHP 5.x script which requires OpenSSL 0.9.8k or higher.

In regard to OpenSSL, I found the following two relevant constants:

```
OPENSSL_VERSION_TEXT (with value 'OpenSSL 1.0.0c 2 Dec 2010')
OPENSSL_VERSION_NUMBER (with value '268435519')
```

Unfortunately, I have no clue how to do the mentioned check on these values.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The source for version 0.9.8k has a constant `OPENSSL_VERSION_NUMBER` of `0x009080bf`

```
<?php

if(OPENSSL_VERSION_NUMBER < 0x009080bf) {
    echo "OpenSSL Version Out-of-Date";
} else {
    echo "OpenSSL Version OK";
}

?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Just for a newbie: what does 0x009080bf mean? Or why, in my case, is '268435519' equal 'OpenSSL 1.0.0c 2 Dec 2010' ?

Comment: @HomeCoder: `268435519` is `0x1000003f` in hexadecimal. `0x1000003f` = `1[0].0[0].0[0]`, while `0x009080bf` = `0[0].9[0].8[0]`.

Comment: 0x009080bf another way to represent a number (hexadecimal notation). The decimal equivalent is 9470143.  Each new version of OpenSSL comes out with a number that is strictly higher than the version before, so you can perform this type of version check.  The text is for humans to read (and cannot be compared with < and >).

Answer (score 8):

If you like the one line command though:

```
php -r "echo OPENSSL_VERSION_NUMBER;"
```

Comment: If you want human-readable output, `OPENSSL_VERSION_TEXT` is much more helpful.

Answer (score 2):

printInfo() output should tell you if you have openSSL support